# UITableViewCell extended over UITableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableView in my iPad application and for some reason the UITableViewCell seems to be wider than my tableView so it's actually hanging off the right side by a few pixels. I tried playing with `cell.contentview` to set it to match the uitableview's width in `cellforRow`, but it didn't change anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the UITableViewCell's frame width in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  Use something like this.

```
 cell.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.tableView.frame.size.width,cell.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work. I am still getting the 10 pixel-ish overhang :|

Comment: When you say "Seems" to be wider than the table are you certain that it is? Are there any layout constraints or auto resizing masks acting on the `UITableView`? Can you share a screen shot of the offending table view cell and table?